# Emacs defining a function that sets arguments to nil

Tags: function, emacs, lisp

I would like to create a nil function that takes any number of symbols and sets them all to nil.

```
(defun clean (as many args as given by user)
  (setq each-arg nil)
)

(clean x y z)
```

How to do this 'cleanly'?

Comment: I don't think you can do that "cleanly" because this operation is fundamentally ugly.  If you show us some example where you think you want this, we'll show you how to do it better.

Comment: well, I actually want the behavior as described here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're not quoting the arguments, it has to be a macro:

```
(defmacro clean (&rest symbols)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (sym) (list 'setq sym 'nil))
               symbols)))
```

Comment: A lot is new for me, `defmacro`, `lambda`, `mapcar`, `&rest`, `,@`. Could you please add some more explanation like why you use these things?

Comment: I read every single of those before, but they are complex. Using this as an example, I think that some others would really benefit from an explanation (at least I really would!).

Comment: That's cool if someone wants to do help you with that.  My point it's better to be self reliant and learn this stuff.  If you have trouble learning it from the manual, file documentation bugs so others in your position can learn easier in the future.

Comment: @Dualinity I think you may want to re-read the [Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html#Macros) chapter. The example in the first part ("Simple Macro") is quite similar to this question. Also see [Backquote](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote).

Comment: Or just:(defmacro clean (&rest symbols)
  `(mapc (lambda (sy) (set sy nil)) ',symbols))

Answer (score 5):

Similar idea as Dmitry, but generates slightly less code:

```
(defmacro clean (&rest variables)
  `(setq ,@(loop for var in variables nconc (list var nil))))

(macroexpand '(clean a b c d))
;; (setq a nil b nil c nil d nil)
```

Regarding your other questions:

- simple, but time consuming way to know is to move the point to the function that you don't know and <kbd>C-h f</kbd> or <kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-function` this will put the function name in the prompt (if it is indeed an Emacs Lisp function) and show the description and, if availably the location in the source code.
- I'll try to explain, but I'm no language reference :)

  - `defmacro` - is similar to function, but it doesn't evaluate arguments. Macros are executed when your code is read and compiled into the bytecode. Their primary goal is to generate other code.
  - `lambda` - is a macro that creates an anonymous function and returns it.
  - `mapcar` - is a high-order function that applies a function to all elements of the list in succession and collects the result into a list in the order it applied the function.
  - `&rest` - is a special keyword in the function's lambda-list (i.e. the definition of parameters) which means literally that the identifier following this symbol is a list of all arguments on the right of it).
  - `,@` is a special operator used in macros, inside back-quote macros. It instructs the reader that the expression following it must be evaluated, treated as list, and all of its conses must be appended to the form that is being currently parsed.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps! I am aware of the `C-h f` and use it a lot, but some of these (like `mapc` or others are just really complex, and I didn't 'get' them).

Comment: `M-x elisp-index-search` is your friend. (And if that doesn't tell you enough, the `I` key will give you a full list of index hits for the given search term.)