# Increment several variables at once, using &rest?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to create a function that allows to:

`(incf vara varb varc vard)`

Instead of

`(incf vara)
(incf varb)
(incf varc)
(incf vard)`

What I do not understand is how to be able to send more arguments, how to define that in a function?

(defun inc (&rest arg)
  (interactive)
  (mapcar 'incf arg)
  )

This increases the argument, but ofcourse does not save them back into the variables.

How to go about this?

Comment: You more-or-less asked this same question less than a fortnight ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292227/emacs-defining-a-function-that-sets-arguments-to-0/14293387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work:

```
(require 'cl)

(setq a 1)
(setq b 2)

(defun inc (&rest arg)
  (interactive)
  (mapc (lambda (x) (incf (symbol-value x))) arg))

(inc 'a 'b)

(message "%s %s" a b) => (2 3)
```

You have to quote each argument otherwise `(inc a b)` becomes `(inc 1 2)` before executing `inc`.

Comment: Is this the way you would advise to do it, using &rest?

Comment: `&rest` gives you ability to don't point out a number of arguments only. For the rest it is like `(defun inc (a b) ..)` or `(defun inc (a b c) ..)`.

Comment: I recommend you use `dolist` instead of `mapc`.  It's slightly more efficient (and the byte-compiler doesn't know how to do the conversion for you).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to be able to write this form as `(my-incf a b c)` without quoting the variable names `a`, `b`, and `c`, make it a macro rather than a function:

```
(defmacro incf+ (&rest vars)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (var) `(incf ,var)) vars)))
```

Check that it expands into the right code using `macroexpand`:

```
(macroexpand '(incf+ var1 var2 var3))
;; => (progn (incf var1) (incf var2) (incf var3))
```

Because variables in Emacs Lisp have dynamic scope by default, you *can* accomplish almost the same thing with a function which takes quoted variable names as arguments.  But the macro version has the advantage that, since it expands into code in the place when it was called, it will work with lexically bound variables as well.  `symbol-value` only works with dynamically bound variables.

You can test this by putting the following in a file and loading it (in Emacs 24 or higher):

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defun incf+fun (&rest vars) 
  (mapc #'(lambda (var) (incf (symbol-value var))) vars))

(defun incf-macro-test ()
  (let ((a 5) (b 7) (c 11))
    (incf+ a b c)
    (list a b c)))

(defun incf-function-test ()
  (let ((a 5) (b 7) (c 11))
    (incf+fun 'a 'b 'c)
    (list a b c)))
```

Evaluating `(incf-macro-test)` will return `(6 8 12)`, but `(incf-function-test)` will enter the debugger with a `(void-variable a)` error.